# Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

On focus my selector creates a dynamic id for usage with a datepicker object only the datepickers months, years and prev/next buttons dont work.

```
$(document).on('focus', ".gfield_list_container tr td:nth-child(2) input" , function(){
 // Gforms doesn't give list fields new ids so we must do it ourselves to enable date picker to work
 $(this).attr('id', makeid());
 $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
 $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

Seen here:

[image: seen here]

I searched around a little and found this:

```
$(this).live('focus', function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1930:'+(new Date).getFullYear()         
    });
});
```

With this approach I have to first click outside the date field, then click inside it to activate the datepicker. Once it's visible whilst the previous/next buttons and months/years now seem to be functional I still can't select the dates I require and the months wont cycle beyond March?

Comment: can you create some fiddle or JSsnippet, so it would be easier for us to help you?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using datepicker from jQuery UI ? If yes, start with the code they are showing as example 
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

and then once it works, tweak it as you need.

Anyway, if you work from from the example you have given, maybe try :

```
$(document).on('focus', ".gfield_list_container tr td:nth-child(2) input" , function(){
 // Gforms doesn't give list fields new ids so we must do it ourselves to enable date picker to work
 $(this).attr('id', makeid());
 $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1930:'+(new Date).getFullYear()});
});
```

Comment: Using the above the select and previous/next now appear to work, however, I can't seem to cycle past the month March for some reason. Another issue also is, upon clicking on a date I'm taken right back to the top of the window with nothing selected from the datepicker. It may be worth noting that I have 3 datepickers on this page.